# Getting the file upload speed with Delphi

Tags: delphi, file-upload

I have coded some tool using Delphi 2010 and clever internet suite for logging into a website and uploading a file.

Everything works fine, and now I would like to add the upload speed rate, but I don't know how to do it.

I have spent the whole day googling around, but it did not bring any positive results.

I was trying in this part:

```
procedure TForm2.clHttp1SendProgress(Sender: TObject; ABytesProceed,
  ATotalBytes: Int64);
begin

end;
```

Could someone please explain me how to do that or just give some tip?

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed

Comment: Very hard to understand  :(

Comment: So you don't know what speed means and how to calculate?

Comment: If i know how to calculate it, i would'nt ask for help..

Comment: Coding and calculating are different. But you can't code if you can't calculate it by hand or know any basic of what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: Coding is my hobby,English  isn't my first language, and i have only finished my basic education !. btw any moderator can close this topic i will try to find a solution by myself or i will give up, have a nice day.

Comment: It's up to you to ask a programming question to a specific problem and show what you have tried so far to solve and where you get stuck. You just post a simple empty method that you get with a doubleclick - not very much. So I just wanted to know what your real problem is (coding or calculating at all). BTW I'm not a native english speaker too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Speed" is defined as an amount per timespan. To calculate you must know what amount and what timespan.

Just store the current amount and the current timestamp and next time you can calculate the speed

```
(current_amount - last_amount)/(current_timestamp - last_timestamp)
```

```
TForm2 = ...
...
private
  FBytesProceed : Int64;
  FTimeStamp : TDateTime;
  FSpeed : double;
end;

procedure TForm2.clHttp1SendProgress(Sender: TObject; ABytesProceed,
  ATotalBytes: Int64);
var
  LTimeStamp : TDateTime;
begin
  LTimeStamp := Now;
  if FBytesProceed < ABytesProceed then
  begin
    // calculating bytes per second
    FSpeed := ( ABytesProceed - FBytesProceed ) {bytes}
            / ( ( LTimeStamp - FTimeStamp ) {days}
              * 24 {hours}
              * 60 {minutes}
              * 60 {seconds} );
  end;
  FBytesProceed := ABytesProceed;
  FTimeStamp := LTimeStamp;
end;
```